# Why would an UnhandledMatchError have no message, and instead only show "..."?

Tags: php

We have a bug to do with a `match` case. We're getting errors in Sentry on production like this:

```
UnhandledMatchError
Unhandled match case '...'
```

When we hit this problem locally we get more of an error message (`Unhandled match case 'Customer...'`) explaining which field is causing the problem.

But on our production system, Sentry and Monolog are only picking up the `...` - they don't give the field name. This makes debugging very tricky.

We've resolved the problem by wrapping the suspect code:

```
try {
    // $violation is a Symfony ConstraintViolation
    return match ($violation->getPropertyPath()) {
       "PropertyPathA" => "something",
       "PropertyPathB" => "somethingElse",
    }
} catch (UnhandledMatchError $e) {
    // Log more details of the error, as well as $e
}
```

But I'd like to understand why the original error is missing the full error string. Is there a PHP setting which hides these errors on a production system?

Comment: Please show actual code that causes the error.

Comment: I suspect this is related to a php.ini setting. On 3lvl.org I get the actual value in the error message, but on my own server I get `...`. Both are running 8.2.7.

Comment: I've added some example code @Barmar. Yes, I think it's a php.ini setting too, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: A simpler example would be just `match('foo') { ... }`

Comment: I don't see any php.ini settings that seem related, I searched for `match`, `case`, and `error`. But I can't think of anything else that might cause this different behavior, since it's not version-dependent.

Comment: Could it be https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.exception-ignore-args? I haven't got time to test it today, but wonder if that's it.

Comment: Seemed like a good guess, but I just tested `ini_set('zend.exception_ignore_args', true);` on 3v3l.org, and the opposite on my server, and it didn't have any effect.